# Reading stops when writing stops

Tags: java, sockets

Two classes. Server and Client. Client sends and server receives.

How I send in client side is like this:

```
        File file = getFile();
        FileInputStream fileIStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedIStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileIStream);
        DataInputStream dataIStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedIStream);
        byte [] buffer = new byte [8*1024];

        DataOutputStream dataOStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        dataOStream.writeUTF(file.getName());
        dataOStream.writeLong(file.length());
        dataOStream.writeUTF(client_name);
        dataOStream.writeUTF(server_name);
        dataOStream.writeInt(1); //just a number

        int read, totalWritten = 0;
        while((read = dataIStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            totalWritten += read;
            dataOStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }            
        System.out.println("Total Written: " + dataOStream.size());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Everything looks fine here but I feel something wrong in the sending event. Because right after sending completed, the receiving at the server side stops immediately. I think in somewhere, somehow, connections are closing but there is nowhere I close the socket or any stream. Here is the server side

```
    try {
        final String fileName = dataIStream.readUTF();
        final long fileSize = dataIStream.readLong();
        final String clientname = dataIStream.readUTF();
        final String servername = dataIStream.readUTF();
        final int number = dataIStream.readInt(); //just a number

        int read, totalRead = 0;
        File outputFile = createFile(outputPath, fileName);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        try {
            byte [] readBuffer = new byte[8*1024];
            while ((read = dataIStream.read(readBuffer)) > 0) {
                totalRead += read;
                outputStream.write(readBuffer, 0, read);
                if (totalRead == fileSize) {
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

If the file sending is ongoing, the reading is fine. Once the sender stops, receiving stops. I cant solve this. Anyone sees my problem?

> Sending and receiving functions run in different threads if that makes any difference.

And I also get UTF reading error but that's not the major issue now. The same thing I did in different application was working fine with UTF and receiving. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

This is how I call sending file

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileInLoop")
        public void run()
        {
            while(isRunning()) //this indicates socket status
            {
                while (!queue.isEmpty()) //a queue with list of files to send continuously
                    sendFile(queue.remove(0))
            }                
        }
    }).start();
```

The Thread is created and started only once.

Comment: Your file sending looks fine, could you post how it is called? Like socket accept and so on.

Comment: "server side stops immediately", does it throws an exception or the loop condition is true?

Comment: @Ivan It waits available data to read in the while loop. Because sending is completed, receiving suddenly stops. The buffered data is like lost. I am not sure if sending is really writing though.

Comment: Have you tried to flush and close the DataOutputStream in the client?

Comment: @Ivan Yes. Even tried flushing after every write and after loop. Same thing happens. What might be stopping the transmission? If I send a file, say 1GB, around half of it is transferred, the rest is not. If the file is small, say 1MB, only around half is transferred as well. The socket is active. If I send two files, half of the first file is received, then the second file's data is written to the first file because it expects more bytes than received for the first file. A little weird.

Comment: Well, did the same sending and receiving event as a separate dummy app. It works. no threading or many clients. What may cause the BufferedReader to stop immediately after client completes sending?